# Postgresql - one ini4 vs two int2 for indexing

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have got a table with millions of rows in postgresql. One row can be represent by eight int4 or sixteen int2 columns.
I want to have one multicolumn (btree) index on this table: create index on mytable(c1,c2,c3,c4,....c8);
I wonder, what is better solution (for performance purpose): one multicolumn index with eight (int4 type) columns or one multicolumn index with sixteen (int2 type) columns.

In other words:

create index on mytable (c_int4_1, c_int4_2, ... c_int4_8);

vs.

create index on mytable (c_int2_1,c_int2_2...c_int2_16);

Answer (score 1):

Whichever most naturally matches the use of the data. Any gains from the more efficient on the btree will be lost again when forcing it into another format.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Both solutions are equal in this context (naturality)